# Sonarcube and handling exception mechanism

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I've implemented some functionality that allows to handle socket connection on application server. Here is excerpt of my code:

```
@Dependent
public class SocketServerService {

  @Resource(name = "DefaultManagedThreadFactory")
  private ManagedThreadFactory threadFactory;

  private ServerSocket serverSocket;
  private Thread socketServerThread;
  private volatile boolean isListening = false;

  public void startListening(int port) {
     socketServerThread = threadFactory.newThread(() ->   listeningOnSocket(port));
     socketServerThread.setName("ServerSocketThread");
     socketServerThread.start();
  }

  private void listeningOnSocket(int port) {
     try {
         serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
         waitForRequestAndProcessData();
     } catch (IOException e) {
         logger.error("Could not listen on socket: " + port, e);
     }
  }

 private void waitForRequestAndProcessData() {
     while (isListening) {
         try {
             final Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
             process(socket);// do something on data received from socket that 
                             // can throw some checked or unchecked exceptions

          } catch (Exception e) {
             logger.error("Error while processing data.", e);
          }
      }
  } 

  private void stopServerSocket() {
      socketServerThread.interrupt();
  }

...
```

}

As you can see I used ManagedThreadFactory to create managable threads. When I used Sonarcube to verify my code it shows the following bug:

**Catch a list of specific exception subtypes instead.**

I know that handling all exception by using `catch (Exception e)` is bad practice but I don't know how to change my code to fix this. I don't want to exit from my `while (isListening) {}` loop when an error will occur in `process` method (I want only log error and process next piece of data from socket). But what type of exception should I catch? Of course I can declare some checked exception in `process` method and catch it in `waitForRequestAndProcessData` method but in this case I will have add `catch (Exception e)` in `process` method. In this case Sonarcube will also show 
**Catch a list of specific exception subtypes instead** message for `process` method. Maybe I should redesign my code in some way? Or in this case caching all exception is not so bad practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ServerSocket.accept()` can only throw the following exceptions:

- `IOException` and subclasses thereof which is a checked Exception.
- Any number of `RuntimeException` and subclasses thereof

Therefor you can replace your catch with:

```
  } catch (IOException | RuntimeException e) {
     logger.error("Error while processing data.", e);
  }
```

and still now for sure that all exceptions will be caught.

You can also make the `RuntimeException` explicit and that would result in:

```
  } catch (IOException | SecurityException | IllegalBlockingModeException e) {
     logger.error("Error while processing data.", e);
  }
```